# Is Makise Kurisu's thesis referred from a real thesis in real life?

Tags: steins-gate

In *Steins;Gate*, Kurisu Makise wrote a thesis about memory uploading.

[image: Kurisu's thesis in-game]

The circuit seems real enough to me that made me wonder if it's referred from a real thesis in real life. I would like to think that it's not, though.

Is Makise Kurisu's thesis referred from a real thesis in real life?

Comment: Seems like a very simplified circuit for a transmitter. The neural applications of human brain are far more complicated. For example. the circuit diagram of VERY old gen Telephone transmitter http://www.circuitstoday.com/telephone-transmitter

Comment: @Arcane that's why I thought it's not real, but the details are pretty well made for a signal transmitter. I did some search in IEEE papers about orbitofrontal cortex and remote viewing but I found no clue.

Answer (score -1):

Just like time travel itself, this is very much part of the science fiction of the anime.
As far as we know memories are physically stored in the brain and can thus not be uploaded or downloaded through telephones.